# PHP cURL connect using IP address instead domain name

Tags: php, curl

I run several servers in the same data center that have internal networking enabled.  In the interests of speed and costs (internal traffic is not billed) I would like to be able to cURL between the various servers on their internal IPs.

I have just discovered that if I attempt something along the lines of

```
curl_init('10.x.x.x);
```

or even

```
curl_init():
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_URL,'https://10.x.x.x/scripttorun.php');
```

does not work.  When I have only a very small quantity of data to send out I can append it as a query string and do a file_get_contents.  However, when the amount of data is too big to send out as a GET request things get messier if I cannot use cURL.

A spot of searching suggested that I could persuade cURL to use IPs by editing the /etc/hosts table.  The problem is that the various servers on the internal network may go on and off line at unpredicatable intervals so I would end up having to poll regularly to see which servers are online, write a script to update /etc/hosts... which gets pretty messy.

Perhaps there is a simple solution that can persuade cURL to use IPs.  After all, file_get/put_contents does so without flinching.  I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able workaround for cURL

Comment: Besides the virtual hostname in nilesh answer, you have to check the firewalls and listening interfaces on the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever have to connect to a server and ask for particular server name you can do it with curl setopt parameters. If you want to get file /index.php from www.mytopsite.com from particular IP (without adding any /etc/hosts mappings) you can do it like this:

```html
$headers = array("Host: www.myfaketopsite.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://10.1.2.3/index.php");
```