# How to get contents of IP address in PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Im trying to use PHP file_get_contents for an IP. Example:

```
echo file_get_contents("1.22.22:2334/pay");
```

However PHP And Curl does not return the contents of the IP address, How would i go about doing this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: is the IP address public or internal? Also is that ip set up to share content? What's returned at the mo?

Comment: That would at least need a protocol prefix `http://…` for the IP to resolve to an actual service. IPs by themselves do *nothing*.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "getting the contents of IP address"? An IP address is just a number. I guess you want to request for some data from a service running on a machine that has that address - What service? Over which protocol?

Comment: @Joni , i think he want to make a curl call to this url .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use curl as `file_get_contents` requires `allow_url_fopen` to be on in the php.ini config file (which is not always the case).

With curl and IP only it should be like:

```
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // headers for ip only
    $headers = array("Host: www.myfaketopsite.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://1.22.22:2334/pay");

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer partly from: [PHP cURL connect using IP address instead domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208610/php-curl-connect-using-ip-address-instead-domain-name)

More information: https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php